# A more secure symmetric encryption key vs. asymmetric key

Tags: encryption, encryption-symmetric, encryption-asymmetric

What are the advantages of having a symmetric encryption algorithm with a lower probability of key retrieval than the asymmetric encryption used for transferal of symmetric key? I can see how it obligates the eavesdropper to concentrate on the asymmetric key, but are there other advantages?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question.

Comment: I'm new at this. Where should I post it?

Comment: Try at [crypto.stackexchange.com](http://crypto.stackexchange.com) .. but first try a search there, your question might already have an answer there.

Comment: Man, thank you. I'll erase from here.

Comment: Do you guys mind flagging my question? I flagged it as off-topic and then blatantly off-topic.

Comment: @ForrestGump: huh? Why flagging your own question when you can just delete it.